# How to write a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class i don't no how to  write test class. This my test class method. Please help me.

```
private static void decommAssets(Map<Id, Custom_Asset__c> assets, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> olis){

        for(OpportunityLineItem o:olis.values()){
            if(o.Fulfillment_Date__c < System.today()){
                assets.get(o.Asset__c).Active__c = 'No';
                assets.get(o.Asset__c).Status__c = 'Off Maintenance';
            } else {
                assets.get(o.Asset__c).Usage_End_Date__c = o.Fulfillment_Date__c;
            }
        }
        try {
            update assets.values(); 
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: there is a lot of great documentation out there, both from Salesforce itself and other great blog posts so I won't go in too much detail. If you want to learn how to write test classes, here is a great place to start: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Answer (score 3):

**First and foremost** I recomends you to **read the** official **introduction** to [Apex Unit Test](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)

Basically, you have to:

1. create a class
2. add the method that will test your code
3. into this/those method you have to create fake data (Take care on system data, read about @seeAllData, but avoid it.)
4. and call the code that you are trying to test
5. finally add an assert to know if your code is doing what it has to do.

   ```
   public class myClass {

       static testMethod void myTest() {
       //create data 

      // Add test method logic using System.assert(), System.assertEquals()



       // and System.assertNotEquals() here.

    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

It will be bit tricky, because you use OpporunityLineItem.
You have to use '(seeAllData = true)' in your code and get standart pricebook because you can't create it in code. then you have to create product2 and pricebookEntry.
Based on this you can create Opportunity and OpportunityLineItem.

```
 @isTest (seeAllData=true)
private class SomeTest {

    static testMethod void someTestMethod(){

        Pricebook2 tmpPriceBook = [ SELECT id, CurrencyIsoCode
                                    FROM Pricebook2
                                    WHERE isStandard=true
                                    LIMIT 1];
        Product2 p2 = new Product2(/** required fields **/);
        insert p2;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(/** required fields **/);
        insert pbe;
        Acount acc = new Acount(/** required fields **/);
        insert acc;
        Contact contact = new Contact(/** required fields **/);
        insert contact;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(/** required fields **/);
        insert opp;
        OpportunityLineItem oppli = new OpportunityLineItem(/** required fields **/);
        insert oppli;

        /** Create and Insert other objects **/

        /** System.assertNotEquals()  Here **/  
    }
}
```